# OpenCV | C++ | Depth Map from Warped Image and Homography Matrix

Tags: c++, opencv, homography

I'm trying to achieve a Depth Map from Stereo Imaging (Two images of the same object that slightly differ/tilted in one direction)

What I've done so far - in this particular order;

- LoadImages
- Grayscale
- Filtering (Gaussian)
- Correct for Radial Distortion & Tilt Correction
- Feature Extraction (SIFT)
- Match features (FLANN-BASED)
- Lowe's Ratio Test to filter Good Matches
- Store Good Matches in vector
- Draw Good Matches
- Extract Pixel Coordinates of Good Matches
- findHomography (RANSAC) // findFundamentalMat (RANSAC)
- (warp perspective to get warp image 2 onto image 1)

I am unsure of the procedure for obtaining a depth map from a homography or fundamental matrix. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "My questions" -- there's the first problem -- this site requires you to ask a single question per... question. You should split this up into several self-contained questions, each focused on a single problem. Ideally, add a [mcve] with example inputs to allow others to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I have changed the post to be more specific :)